# Extending Titanium WebViewProxy for Android - Build error

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules, titanium-proxy, titanium-android

I need to extend Titanium's Android Webview with some additional functionality, however I'm not able to build my titanium project after including my created module.

My module has the titanium-ui.jar on it's build path and I have copied the original Titanium WebViewProxy.java into my module project. I haven't added any custom code to WebViewProxy.java yet.

This is the project hierarchy of my module, together with the build.properties file.
[image]

When building the module, I get an exception but the module seems to get built anyway, this must have something to do with the final problem. When I remove the WebViewProxy.java and keep the titanium-ui.jar on my build path, building the module and including it in my titanium project works fine.

Here's the full console log of the build script of the module: http://pastebin.com/G2LSkFLF

This is what happens when I try to run my titanium project using the generated module (the one, that threw the exception while building)

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this? Maybe some different approach at all? I have some special url schemes in my app and I need to handle them. I have already a similar module for iOS, which works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution. It was so easy... The WebViewProxy.java had to be adjusted a little bit.

```
@Kroll.proxy(creatableInModule=UIModule.class, propertyAccessors = {
```

has to be

```
@Kroll.proxy(creatableInModule=CustomwebviewModule.class, propertyAccessors = {
```

UIModule.class has to be replaced with the class name of your Module.